# what does happen if I call run() method myself?

Tags: java, multithreading

in the main method if I write this:

```
Thread aThread = new Thread();
aThread.run();
```

what will happen???

Answer (score 10):

It will run in **current** thread. You will **not start new thread** this way.

But that doesn't really matter in your example since you gave new Thread no code to run anyway.

Answer (score 3):

The thread that runs the `main()` code is the current thread. Creating a `Thread` object and calling one of its methods (other than `start()`) is like calling a method of class `Integer` or `String` - it doesn't create a new actual thread.

In your code example, execution of the main method will continue only when the `run()` method has finished running. This means that if the `run()` method has an endless loop (let's say it's waiting for incoming requests), then the `main()` method will never continue running, even if there are more lines of code after the call to `run()`.

Calling `aThread.start()` creates a new actual thread (represented by the object `aThread`), makes the new thread call the `run()` method, and returns execution of the original thread to the next line in the `main()`. This means that the new thread can run around in circles forever, but it doesn't stop the `main()` code from creating more threads or performing other tasks.

Answer (score 3):

It will just run like you're calling a normal method. So the method will be running in the same thread that calls the method.

Answer (score 1):

It will run in the current Thread not in **new Thread** So If you call run method yourself it is meaningless. Because It doesn't create a new Thread.

Answer (score 0):

If you call the start-method on a Thread class, the start-method will return after a while, but in concurrency will run the content of the run-method. If you call the run-method directly it will be executed and return to the caller, after the method is completely done - as every normal method call.